# "Draft" mode for document

Tags: conditionals

Suppose you want to keep two versions of the same document: one where you highlight changes and one where you show the final result. How can I use a "debug" or "test" mode to turn on/off my `\textbf` commands? Example:

```
\documentclass[phd,testing]{nuthesis}
\begin{document}
    This is old.
    \if testing, \textbf{This is new.}
\end{document}
```

I would like the following when in testing:

This is old.
**This is new.**

And this when not in testing:

This is old.
This is new.

Comment: `\newif\iftesting` and then `\newcommand{\testing}[1]{\iftesting \textbf{#1}\else #1\fi}`.  Then you can turn it "on" with `\testingtrue` (the default is `\testingfalse`). It can be done mid-document.

Comment: Please read this useful information: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), to learn about and improve your way for writing questions on this site.

Comment: You might also use \DeclareOption{testing}{\testingtrue}

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/topic/cond-comp